# Make elements appear only if a specific radio button is checked in on GSP (Grails)

Tags: javascript, html, grails, groovy, gsp

There's a couple of  elements and a  element that I want to be only visible when a specific radio button is selected. Here's those   and  elements:

```
<td align="right><input type="text" id="seconds" name="seconds" value="30"> <label for="seconds" seconds</label></td>
<td align="right><b>Some text here</b></td>
```

Here's the gsp code to populate the radio buttons where its getting the values from an Enum list and if ANY radio button is checked, then someFunction() is called:

```
<g:each in="$RadioButtonEnum.getAllEnumList()}" var="buttonItem"> //get the values of radio buttons from Enum
<input type="radio" name="buttonAction"
    value="${buttonItem.key}" <g:if test ="${buttonItem.key==command}">checked</g:if>
    onclick=someFuction();   //if radio button is selected, it does something
    ${buttonItem}<br>
<g:each>
```

I'm having trouble understanding the implementation of how would I go about it if I were to make those two elements appear ONLY if buttonItem="RadioButton1" was checked? Can I do it with `<script>` as well?

Comment: Are you trying to show the elements when rendering your template or when a user interacts with the radio button? So on the backend or on the frontend?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier When the user interacts with the radio button. So, when the `RadioButton1` is selected, those 2 elements should appear. If any other Radio button is selected or if no radio button is selected, then by default those 2 elements should be invisible. If you look at the code, right now, both of those elements are visible by default. And if any radio button is selected, `somefunction()` is being called.

Comment: It's the easiest to check the `value` of an input. What value does `buttonItem.key` produce? Could include a small example with *rendered* html? Preferably one row that remains unchanged, one row that will be hidden. And a couple of rendered inputs, including the one that you need. That way I will know for sure what I'm working with.